# How can I redirect to file and pipe it out to another app?

Tags: bash

Right now I have:

```
{ /usr/bin/node server.js 2>&3 | logger -p local0.notice -t node_server } 3>&1 1>&2 | logger -p local0.err -t node_server
```

But I would like both standard out and error to goto a console.log file as well. How can I add that to the mix?

Answer (score 2):

In general

```
program1 |& tee err_out_log.txt | program2
```

Note that `|&` is a Bash 4 feature that combines stderr and stdout;

Answer (score 1):

You want to use tee

```
$ man tee
TEE(1)                    BSD General Commands Manual                   TEE(1)

NAME
     tee -- pipe fitting

SYNOPSIS
     tee [-ai] [file ...]

DESCRIPTION
     The tee utility copies standard input to standard output, making a copy
     in zero or more files.  The output is unbuffered.
```

Comment: In it's current form this is merely a comment and should have linked to the man page.